# lumen - Why does PHPUnit register test returns 405?

Tags: phpunit, lumen

I want to make phpunit tests for lumen app, like :

```
public function testRegisterUser()
{
    $newUserData = [
        'name'      => 'test_user',
        'email'     => 'test_user@mail.com',
        'password'  => Hash::make('111111'),
        'status'    => 'A',
        'has_debts' => false
    ];

    $response = $this->get('/api/v1/register', $newUserData); // http://localhost:8000/api/v1/register
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

But running tests I got 405 error :

```
1) PagesTest::testRegisterUser
Expected response status code [200] but received 405.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 405.

/ProjectPath/vendor/illuminate/testing/TestResponse.php:177
/ProjectPath/vendor/illuminate/testing/TestResponse.php:99
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:415
/ProjectPath/tests/PagesTest.php:27
```

Why I got 405 Method Not Allowed ? I postman I check my method : https://prnt.sc/207bu03

Method /api/v1/register in postman has no any token protection.
How to make my test working ?

**UPDATED BLOCK :**
I got error :

```
Error: Call to undefined method PagesTest::getJson()
```

If I modify :

```
$response = $this->getJson('/api/v1/register', $newUserData);
```

method getJson is mentioned here : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests
But on this page I see in test file header:
namespace Tests\Feature;

But not in my generated lumen test file.

In my routes/web.php I have :

```
$router->group(['prefix'=>'api/v1'], function() use($router){

    $router->post('/register','AuthController@register');
    $router->post('/login', 'AuthController@login');

    $router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () use ($router) {
        $router->get('/profile', 'UserProfileController@index');
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you maybe have to use `$this->getJson` instead of `$this->get`.

It is not `http://localhost:8000` as you are testing, you are not literally accessing the URL. It is simulating that.

Also share your `api.php` or routes file and the controller please (also the middlewares working on that URL).

---

Looking at the [Lumen's documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing#application-testing) I can see that there is no `getJson`, my bad. You have to use `$this->json('GET'` instead.

Comment: Please look at UPDATED BLOCK

Comment: Look at my updated answer